# What method do I use when wanting to display multiple images and respond to user interaction?

Tags: ios

Alright, so I have 5 custom images that I want in my game.

So each variable for example will have a value set with it, image 1 = 1, image 2 = 2, etc. I want the user to be able to press one of these images and when they do, it will change from say image 5 to image 4.

Do I need to put these images in an array/dictionary/etc? I honestly have no idea how to go about it so dont know what to search for on google.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Buttons? What should the interface look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use imageViews and add a gesture recognizer to each imageView, and then give each imageView tags in order to organize them.  You can set tags in storyboard by pressing the imageView and then entering the tag under the shield.  Each imageView should have a distinct tag.  I'm giving a programatic example below for clarity, though.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(wasTapped:)];
tap.delegate = self;
imageView.tag = 1;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

When an imageView is tapped the selector will be called and you can change the imageView like so.

```
-(void) wasTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
 {
    UIImageView * imageView = (UIImageView*) recognizer.view;
    if (imageView.tag == 1){
       // change image to something else
       UIImage * newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage"];
       imageView.image = newImage;
    }
 }
```

You may have to call `[imageView setNeedsDisplay]` to make the new image appear.  You also will have to devise some system to organize the imageViews.  You may also have to set `imageView.userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`.